# How can I make folder in another folder? - Python

Tags: python, directory

I want to make subfolder in another folder. I can make main folder but I don't know how to make other folder in this.

```
import os

fol = os.makedirs('2020')
```

Comment: `os.makedirs('2020/other/folder')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `makedirs` you can do at once

```
 os.makedirs('2020/subfolder/subsubfolder')
```

and it should create `2020`, next `2020/subfolder`, and next `2020/subfolder/subsubfolder`

---

If you already created folder `2020` then you can also use path with `2020/` at the beginning to create subfolder

```
 os.makedirs('2020/subfolder')
```

or you can change folder and then create subfolder without using `2020/`

```
 os.chdir('2020')
 os.makedirs('subfolder')
```

---

**BTW:** probably since Python 3.6 or 3.7 you can use `exist_ok=True` to skip creating if folder already exist.

```
 os.makedirs('2020/subfolder', exist_ok=True)
```

Without `exist_ok=True` it would raise error if folder already exist. And you would need this:

```
if not os.path.exists('2020/subfolder'):
    os.makedirs('2020/subfolder')
```

Comment: @AdamWiśnioch feel free to accept the answer if it helped you. That's how we say "thanks" to useful answers. ;)

Comment: I added more details in answer (PL: dodałem więcej szczegółów w odpowiedzi)